NullPointerException persists after removing Firebase Remote Config from project
I Initially used Firebase Remote Config to fetch a string in my Android project.

Started experiencing the following NullPointerException issue related to Firebase Remote Config.

java.lang.NullPointerException - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
- Took various troubleshooting steps:

Cleaned and rebuilt the project.
Removed Firebase Remote Config dependency.
Removed all relevant code related to Firebase Remote Config.

- Ensured:

No cached files related to Firebase Remote Config.

No transitive dependencies on Firebase Remote Config.

Configuration files are clean from Firebase Remote Config remnants.

All code related to Remote Config removed from the project.

Updated all SDKs and libraries to their latest versions.

Consulted Firebase documentation for cleanup steps.


This is the top crash occurring in my app, and I Request guidance on further troubleshooting steps or potential reasons why the NullPointerException persists even after removing Firebase Remote Config completely from the project.
